# How to use existing relational database with elasticsearch

Tags: database, elasticsearch

I am reading about the `Elasticsearch`, but one question that is always coming to my head: if I have an already existing Relational Database, how can I start using the `Elasticsearch` with it. From my understanding every thing must be stored in a non relational way (That's what I see from videos and the official documentation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont need to convert your existing data into non relational way.. there are few `elasticsearch-jdbc` tools, called `rivers` that will do the task. You just configure them and they are designed to handle the indexes that must be stored on elasticsearch server.

You can read more about it [here](https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-river-jdbc).

Comment: so, how will the types and data in general be correctly constructed, since tables related with foreign keys are different in a non relational DB?

Comment: yeah.. there is no concept of joins in non relational databases.. elasticsearch handles relational joins by creating nested JSON objects.

Comment: so, if I have a web application that is connected to relational database, and I want to use the elastic search, does that mean that I should have two types of databases? a relational one for the web application, and a non-relational for the search?

Comment: No no.. that is not what i meant! When you use elasticsearch for searching.. that means you are creating indexes on elasticsearch server. These indexes are stored as documents containing json objects.. And in a way you are using two datastores.. one relational-where all your data resides, and one indexing store- where only indexed data is stored. Hope this answers your question.